# Restaurar Base de datos Sql Sever 2014 a Sql Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, data

alguna recomendación se los agradecería este es mi caso:

**1. Base de datos del backup SQL Server 2014**

Versión Sql Server 12.0.4100

'C:\FILE_Cada_4_hrs.bak'

**2. Restaurar en Sql Server 2016**

SQL Query:

```
RESTORE DATABASE NAME FROM DISK = 'C:\FILE_Cada_4_hrs.bak'
```

> Mensaje Error:
>
> Msg 3169, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The database was backed up on a
>   server running version 12.00.4100. That version is incompatible with
>   this server, which is running version 11.00.5058. Either restore the
>   database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is
>   compatible with this server. Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Si tengo mi base de datos en Sql server 2016

Mi servidor esta con la versión  11.0.5058.0:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna recomendación para restaurar ?

¿Habrá manera de cambiar que mi servido cuando lo ejecuto con Sql Server 2016 no tome la versión 11.05058 si no la versión  del 2016?

Comment: Puede que tengas instaladas varias versiones de SQL Server. Claramente indica que es la versión 2012 (11.0). Si estás convencido que tienes instalada la versión 2016 entonces tendrá otro nombre de instancia.

Comment: El que tu cliente sea 2016, no cambia el hecho de que el servidor siga siendo 2012. No importa como te conectes, no hay forma de restaurar ese respaldo de forma directa.

Comment: @RogerTorné Si tengo otras versiones de Sql Server menores a 2016 , sobre lo que indica no me aparece otra instancia diferente local en mi maquina, ¿Habrá alguna manera de abrir mi instancia con la versión de Sql 2016? , le agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: Abre una nueva en blanco y ejecuta `select @@VERSION`, así sabrás la versión que tienes

Comment: @RogerTorné  Esta es mi version Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64) , si he instalado Sql server 2016 por que no me da la nueva version , ¿Hubo algun detalle en la instalacion? ¿Alguna solución que recomiende?, agradezco sus respuestas.

Comment: Lo que parece que has instalado es el cliente SQL Server Management Studio 2016, pero no la base de datos. Si me equivoco, deberás encontrar el nombre de la instancia. Puedes probar ejecutando `reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL`

Answer (score 0):

Hola Alexander Morales:

Si tienes varias instancias o motores instalados en tú ordenador, entonces puedes verlas desde varios sitios.

Busca en tus programas instalados el SQL Server Configuration Manager (lo distinguiras fácilmente por el icono rojo).

[image: Sql Server Configuration Manager]

En el árbol de la izquierda, el primer nodo es Servicios de SQL Server, y ahí verás como entre los nombres de los servicios encuentras 1 o varios que se llaman SQL Server (xxxx)

En la imagen de ejemplo se puede distinguir una instancia SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) versión 2017 y una instancia SQL Server (SQL2019).

No es el nombre de ninguna de las dos instancias, pero me indica que tengo dos servicios de windows (dos motores o instancias) instalados y que uno de ellos, en este caso, está detenido, por tanto no funciona. (Botón derecho sobre el mismo, iniciar).

También puedo verlos si desplego la configuración de red y de Sql Native client.

En tú caso, ya que tienes un 2012 funcionando, de lo cual no hay duda, deberías de tener la otra instalada.

Además esta instalado y funcionando otro servicio, que te ayudará para esto. El SQL Server Browser. Si no lo tienes ejecutándose, inicialo.

Una vez tengas la instancia y el browser funcionando, desde el management studio puedes buscar la instancia "perdida".

Abres el Management y en la ventana de conexión y en el desplegable de Server name, pulsa en el mismo.

[image: Server name]

Luego busca en Database Engine.

[image: Motores]

Nota: El firewall de tú sistema, puede penalizar la búsqueda.

Comment: Gracias por su comentario.Solo tenia una instancia instalada en 2012.